# Check execution error: timed out waiting for checker pod to report in

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks

I am trying to create the custom check in kuberhealthy just to check cosmosDB http response. When I see the check on interface, it gives me error: "Check execution error: default/cosmoscheck: timed out waiting for checker pod to report in".

In pod logs I get the proper response that I am supposed to see, but not on kuberhealthy interface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Eqr.png)

```
apiVersion: comcast.github.io/v1
kind: KuberhealthyCheck
metadata:
  name: cosmoscheck
  namespace: default
spec:
  runInterval: 10m
  timeout: 10m
  podSpec:
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 999
      fsGroup: 999
    containers:
      - name: cosmoscheck
        image: cosmoscheck:1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
          - name: COSMOSDB_URL
            value: "........................"
          - name: COSMOSDB_AUTH_TOKEN
            value: "......................."
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Comment: The checker pod might be running out of resources (CPU, memory) during its execution, causing it to take longer than expected. Check the resource limits and requests specified in the pod configuration. Make sure to adjust the resource limits based on the requirements of your checker pod.


resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "200m"
            memory: "256Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "128Mi"

Comment: Still getting the same error. Not sure if it is because of resources or something else. The inbuilt checks work fine, only custom check creates the problem.

Comment: Can you share below these data-
the logs of the Kuberhealthy pod something like this- kubectl logs -n kuberhealthy kuberhealthy-0
 the logs of the checker pod to see if it completed successfully and reported back to Kuberhealthy. Something like this- kubectl logs -n default <checker-pod-name>

Comment: The pod was not running completely. It was throwing an error. I found that there is need of having external client while creating a custom kuberhealthy check in python. When I installed that and used pre-defined functions of client, my check ran successfully.

Comment: Great, Can you post the fix as an answer on this question? It'll be helpful for the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a custom check in go or python make sure to add kh-client. The normal script without using the in-built functions of this client can give error.
[Refer link for details](https://github.com/kuberhealthy/kuberhealthy/tree/master/clients/python#client-python)